# Problem showing External List in a page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, external-content-type, external-list

I have a external content type that is showed in section of lists (Insert in Ribbon). I want to add it to a page but when is added, It shows list of **BDC Identity**, and when I click on them, main data are showed. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question found on [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/5c7641fe-270e-49d5-bf39-5011d242d19a).

Their suggestion was to add the External list like so:
Site Action > More Options > External List.

Also, a more detailed answer with screeenshots on [Technet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/d867f87f-f95f-42b2-83e3-d75454e0e378).